# Angular 2 onclick add new item in array

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create new list item(value from api)on button press but don't know how to do it. Any help please?
here is the code:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let joke of jokes">{{joke.value}}</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="loadMore">more jokes</button>
`,
providers: [RandomService]

})
export class PocetnaComponent  { 
jokes: Joke[];

constructor(private jokesService: RandomService){
this.jokesService.getRandomJokes().subscribe(jokes => {this.jokes = 
[jokes]});
}

loadMore(){
this.jokes.push();
}

}
 interface Joke{
 id: number;
 value: string;
}
```

here is the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RandomService {  
constructor(private http: Http){
    console.log('working');

}
getRandomJokes(){
    return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

Comment: first you need to call your api inside loadMore function once you got result then you need to use 
this.jokes = _.union(this.jokes, apiResult) ;
hope so this will help you

Comment: Not too sure what you are expecting to happen with this code. your `this.jokes.push()` has no parameters, so you are pushing nothing. Can you add a little more detail?

Comment: isn't there a simpler way to do it? And can you write a complete function?

Comment: loadMore() {  
this.RandomService.getRandomJokes().subscribe(jokes => {this.jokes = _.union(this.jokes, apiResult) ; });
}

you can use like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems...

You have this interface:

```ts
interface Joke{
 id: number;
 value: string;
}
```

what you are receiving is much more properties, so you'd need to pick the properties you want:

```ts
getRandomJokes(){
  return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .map(res => res.json());
    // pick the properties you want/need
    .map(joke => <Joke>{id: joke.id, value: joke.value})
}
```

Then you have problems in the subscribe, you should push the data to your `jokes` array and not do:

```ts
.subscribe(jokes => {this.jokes = [jokes]})
```

but:

```ts
.subscribe(joke => this.jokes.push(joke)}
```

notice above that I named this `(joke => this.jokes.push(joke))` to make it clearer that you are actually just receiving one joke.

Also I would remove the request from the constructor, we have the OnInit hook for this. Also I would apply the request in a separate function, so that it's easy to call when you want to retrieve new jokes and also therefore reuse the function, so something like this:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.getJoke()
}

getJoke() {
  this.jokesService.getRandomJokes()
    .subscribe(joke => {
       this.jokes.push(joke)
    })    
}
```

So then in your template just call `getJoke` when you want to retrieve a new joke:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let joke of jokes">{{joke.value}}</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="getJoke()">more jokes</button>
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgcLT8Dfafy5JSZegqNR?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

Just push an empty object

```
this.jokes.push({});
```

or if its going to be hooked up to a modal 
Create a class and push that

```
Class IJoke {
 id: number;
 value: string;
 constructor(){
 }
}
this.jokes.push(new IJoke());
```

Or if you want to push from an API

```
@Injectable()
export class RandomService {  
constructor(private http: Http){
    console.log('working');

}
getRandomJokes(){
    return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
getNextJoke(){
    return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/next')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

Directive

```
loadMore(){
    this.jokesService.getNextJoke().subscribe(joke => {
        this.jokes.push(joke); 
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if you load some random jokes and you want to load one more, or if you want to keep loading random jokes. If the later, you will want to take out the next function, and instead init your jokes array and keep pushing/applying to it. like so

```
jokes: Joke[] = new Array();
constructor(private jokesService: RandomService){
this.jokesService.getRandomJokes().subscribe(jokes => {
    this.jokes.push(jokes)
});
```

Comment: Push from an API goes into service? (result => this.jokes.push(result)); - it says jokes doesn't exist

Comment: Yeah because jokes is in your directive. When i answered, you will have to return a value from the service and subscribe to it in your directive.