# Angular 2 getting json data from api to array

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to fetch JSON data to the array, and with the press of a button to create a new list. Any solutions?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RandomService } from '../services/random.service';

@Component({
selector: 'pocetna',
template: `
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let joke of jokes">{{joke.value}}</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="getJoke()">more jokes</button>`,

providers: [RandomService]
})
export class PocetnaComponent  { 
jokes:Joke[] = [];

constructor(private jokesService: RandomService){}

ngOnInit() {
this.getJoke()
}

getJoke() {
this.jokesService.getRandomJokes()
.subscribe(joke => {
   this.jokes.unshift(joke)
})    
}
}
interface Joke{
id: number;
value: string;
}
```

This is how my service looks like,
I think I'm missing something in it

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RandomService {
constructor(private http: Http){
console.log('working');
}
getRandomJokes(){
 return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
.map(res => res.json()) 
.map(joke => <Joke>{id: joke.id, value: joke.value});
}

}
```

This code worked before restarting application but now this line of code says it can't find :

```
.map(joke => <Joke>{id: joke.id, value: joke.value});
```

Comment: Does your solution work? Your question doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: it's not working, it isn't fetching any data

Comment: What do you mean with *create a new list*?

Comment: with a press of a button to push an API into the array and display it as an 
new <li>

Comment: I don't get this... What is the difference between this question and your previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44185135/6294072

Comment: same question and the plunker demo works, but for some reason i can't implement the code to make it work - here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/XgcLT8Dfafy5JSZegqNR?p=preview

Comment: Well check it, you have errors... errors in the `loadMore` function and in your template. You have the answer fine there in your previous question ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 onclick add new item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185135/angular-2-onclick-add-new-item-in-array)

Comment: hey AJT_82, in the service it says:cannot find the name <Joke>

Comment: Have you imported your interface there?

Comment: interface is in the component, and <Joke> is in the service, i'm not even joking

Comment: Well you need to import the interface to the service, so that you can refer to `Joke`. `import { Joke } from 'whateverPathItsStoredIn'`

Comment: hey i reedited the question. service is allready imported to a component

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAND IT'S WORKIIIIIINGGGGG!!!

Comment: Did you get it to work? like I said, you need to import the interface to your service so that you in the service can use the interface :)

Comment: yes of course, thank you so much :)))

Comment: hey AJT_82, wanna solve a new puzzle? 
 ;D    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220829/angular-2-fetching-data-from-query-string

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to convert the json returned in the api to array loop through the json and convert it into array

```
 loadMore() {
        this.jokes = this.service.getRandomJokes()
            .subscribe(joke => { 
 const getdata = [];
 for(let key in data){
getdata.push(data[key]);
} 
this.jokes =getdata
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random 
it's response a object.

Make response with a array

```
[
    {
      "category": null,
      "icon_url": "https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png",
      "id": "RPVWYzLySH277dwK-Se3PQ",
      "url": "http://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/RPVWYzLySH277dwK-Se3PQ",
      "value": "Chuck Norris is allowed to draw pictures of Mohammad"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you've got problem with parsing data in the response.

You can try this:

```js
.map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
  );
```

OR:

```js
.map((res: Response) => {
  let data = (res.json() || {}).data;
  return data;
});
```