# fetching data from query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to fetch data from this URL:https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=chuck
(chuck is the search term, it can be anything else).

I want to get the value property from the array. Postman gets me this:

```
{
"total": 9735,
"result": [
{
  "category": [
    "dev"
  ],
  "icon_url": "https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png",
  "id": "zdj0bfkjsmup6pkb2rpmbw",
  "url": "http://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/zdj0bfkjsmup6pkb2rpmbw",
  "value": "Chuck Norris is the only human being to display the Heisenberg 
  uncertainty principle - you can never know both exactly where and how 
  quickly he will roundhouse-kick you in the face."
 },
```

my service(edited):

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Joke } from '../joke'

@Injectable()
export class PretragaService {
constructor(private http: Http){}
searchJokes(str: string){return 
this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=' + str)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .map(joke => {return joke.value});
}

}
```

Component(edited):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PretragaService } from '../services/pretraga.service';

@Component({
selector: 'pretraga',
template: `
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="pretraži" 
[(ngModel)]="searchJoke"
name="searchJoke" (keyup)="searchJokes()">
<div *ngIf="searchRes">
<div *ngFor="let joke of searchRes">
<ul>
<li>{{joke}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
`,
providers: [PretragaService]
})
export class PretragaComponent {
searchJoke: string;
searchRes: any[]=[];

constructor(private searchService: PretragaService){

}
searchJokes(){
   this.searchService.searchJokes(this.searchJoke)
   .subscribe(joke => {
   this.searchRes = joke;
});
}
```

I have the class that represents an object:

```
export class Joke{
value: string;
```

}

Comment: So you are getting value property in your json object what else is required.? Your question is not clear ! Please elaborate.

Comment: It all depends on API, so just check the API documentation if you can pass some conditional parameters in Url to fetch just the values or if it is your API then modify it send back only values. Even if not, you can easily modify the object coming from response to just get the values . Like var myArray = obj.result.map(function(res) {return res.value}). And then you have myArray  as an array of all the retrieved values

Comment: i'm probably mapping it wrong, i'll edit the question

Comment: when i execute my code, error says: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

// Modify your myService class :

```
    searchJokes(str: string){return 
    this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=' + str)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .map(joke => {return joke.value});
    }
```

// and component :

```
    searchJoke: string;
    searchRes: any[]=[];

    constructor(private searchService: PretragaService){

    }
    searchJokes(){
       this.searchService.searchJokes(this.searchJoke)
       .subscribe(joke => {
       this.searchRes = joke;
    });
```

Comment: is something wrong with this html? <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="pretraži" [(ngModel)]="searchJoke"
   name="searchJoke" (keyup)="searchJokes()">
   <div *ngIf="searchRes">
   <div *ngFor="let joke of searchRes">
   {{joke.value}}
   </div>
   </div>

Comment: After making the changes as mentioned in answer above your values as an array is in this.searchRes. so just render it directly , instead of {{joke.value}} it should be {{joke}}
You may even check the values in this.searchRes by printing it in console.log(this.searchRes)

Comment: it doesn't render, i changed it to {{joke}}, and console returns undefined

Comment: this is html <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="pretraži" [(ngModel)]="searchJoke"
   name="searchJoke" (keyup)="searchJokes()">
   <div *ngIf="searchRes">
   <div *ngFor="let joke of searchRes">
   <ul>
   <li>{{joke}}</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>

Comment: the console returns empty arrays []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: searchJokes(str: string){
    var jsonFormat = this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=' + str).map(res => res.json());
  var finalValue = jsonFormat.map(joke => {return joke.value});
console.log('JsonFormat', JSON.stringify(jsonFormat );
console.log('FinalValue',JSON.stringify(finalValue ));
console.log('arguement',str);
    } 
//make above changes in your service file and let me know all the console.log results.

Comment: i got this: JsonFormat {"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}}
pretraga.service.ts:12 FinalValue {"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}},"operator":{}}
pretraga.service.ts:12 arguement a

Comment: and in the component: .subscribe(joke => {
       this.searchRes = joke; - says subscribe doesn't exist on type void

Comment: what did you receive in console.log('arguement',str);

Comment: typed 'a' in the console and got: arguement a

Comment: You should have received 'chuck' in console instead of 'a'  that means you are passing wrong argument in your service class itself. This means this.searchJoke is not getting the correct value that is 'chuck' from component itself.  I doubt if you have followed the answer from code .You should verify if you have written code properly.

Comment: i copy/pasted the whole code now, in the service when i paste {return
         this.http.get - like that, i get an error saying unreachable code detected. Pasting like this; return this.http.get - has no errors but still doesn't render anything

Comment: service looks like this: import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Joke } from '../joke'

@Injectable()
export class PretragaService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    searchJokes(str: string){return this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=' + str)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .map(joke => {return joke.value});
    }
                        
    }